# Работа с файлами изображений

Tags: графика, изображения, c++

Здравствуйте! Нужно открыть файл-изображение, даже цветное изображение, и работать с пикселями файла(сравнивать, менять и т.п.). Файл формата bmp. Можете помочь полезной ссылкой, книжкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://opencv.org/

Comment: Не знал про такое... Спасибо!

Comment: Возник еще вопрос,... Открываю файл на бинарное чтение, даже могу копировать его... а как узнать размер картинки bmp?

Comment: @Alerr: как-то так:

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imgpath);
    if (!image.data)
    {
        // problem opening file, handle it
    }
    int pixelWidth = image.cols;
    int pixelHeight = image.rows;

Answer (score 2):

Заголовок bmp состоит из двух структур с необходимой вам информацией, приведенных ниже, после которых идут непосредственно данные.

```
    #pragma pack(2)
    struct
    {
        unsigned short bfType;           /* Magic number for file */
        unsigned int   bfSize;           /* Size of file */
        unsigned short bfReserved1;      /* Reserved */
        unsigned short bfReserved2;      /* ... */
        unsigned int   bfOffBits;        /* Offset to bitmap data */
    } bitmap_file_header;
    #pragma pack()

    struct                     
    {
        unsigned int   biSize;           /* Size of info header */
        int            biWidth;          /* Width of image */
        int            biHeight;         /* Height of image */
        unsigned short biPlanes;         /* Number of color planes */
        unsigned short biBitCount;       /* Number of bits per pixel */
        unsigned int   biCompression;    /* Type of compression to use */
        unsigned int   biSizeImage;      /* Size of image data */
        int            biXPelsPerMeter;  /* X pixels per meter */
        int            biYPelsPerMeter;  /* Y pixels per meter */
        unsigned int   biClrUsed;        /* Number of colors used */
        unsigned int   biClrImportant;   /* Number of important colors */
    } bitmap_info_header;
```

Comment: Спасибо... Но я хочу сам, "своими руками" все пиксели менять... Захотел повернуть картинку, ну, пиксели местами переставить... Переставил вроде как, в винхексе посмотрел... Но ожидания не оправдались, картинка как-то видоизменилась(поворачивал bmp 2x2). С чем бы это могло быть связано? Как вообще пиксели в картинке идут? Какая последовательность? 
так: 12

     34
А в винхексе 4321?

Comment: Пиксели идут стандартно: от верхнего левого края, до правого нижнего. В 24-битом bmp каждый пиксель кодируется 3-мя 8 битными значениями в последовательности синий, зеленый, красный. Данные начинаются с 54-го байта (первые 54 - как рас те две структуры) и количество данных равно biSizeImage байт.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Html>
```

Comment: Это ссылка, книжка или проверка на html injection?

Comment: Может глупый вопрос, информация из сети что-то не помогла... Где в bmp начинается картинка??? Откуда? Открыл в winhexe, поэкспериментировал-безуспешно...

Comment: %X %s %s %S %s

Comment: черт, что-то не срывается стек от лишних спецификаторов...